# How do I validate my input field with these restrictions

Tags: javascript, angular

So i am trying to validate a field with some restrictions. My setup looks correct but for some reason I am not getting the right results. User can enter alphanumeric characters with or without a period (".") and a single space between the characters. Here is what the HTML looks like:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
     <label>Address </label>
     <input type "text" class="form-control" id="address" addressDirective [whiteSpaceAllowed]="true"> 
 </div>
```

TS:

```
constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {}

buildForm() {
 this.form = this.fb.group({
 address: ['', [Validators.pattern('[A-Za-z0-9. ]')]]
});
```

ADDRESS-DIRECTIVE.TS

```
@Directive({
selector: '[addressDirective]'
})

export class AddressDirective {

@Input() 
whiteSpaceAllowed: boolean = false;

private regexWithWhiteSpace = new RegExp(/^[A-Za-z0-9. ]*$/g);

private specialKeys: Array<>string = ['Backspace', 'Tab','End','Home','.'];

constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

@HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
   let current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
   let next: string = current.concat(event.key);
   if (next && !this.whiteSpaceAllowed && !String(next).match(this.regexWithWhiteSpace)) {
       event.preventDefault();
     }
  }
}
```

The input gives invalid errors when I enter alphanumerics with periods separated by a single space. How do I fix this?

Acceptable inputs can only be:

- Alphanumerics with single space, with or without "." character
- No space can appear before or after period character

Acceptable inputs:

```
"ABC12" //alphanumeric, periods not required
"ABC12. dE4" // single spaced no periods before or after
```

Answer (score 1):

you have typo in your html. `S` is lowercase when it should be `whiteSpaceAllowed`. In the directive there is a typo at `export class`. On the line where onKeyDown is specified, `current` is a variable that comes from where? for me it works replacing `current` for `this.el.nativeElement.value`

Comment: thanks, I updated the changes but I'm still able to type multiple spaces between alphanumeric characters in the input. I am also able to enter a period before an alphanumeric character. Should be alphanumeric, single spaced with a period allowed in between

Comment: your regex doesn't check for these restrictions. and these restrictions you point out on comment are not well described at your question. I suggest you to edit your question to say what patterns are allowed, you could even add examples what is accepted and what is not.

Comment: thanks, just fixed and added the examples